# Merge SQL scripts for row condition and table merging

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have these following SQL codes to do clean-up tasks:

1. `SELECT` the first *n*-rows from the table that satisfies a condition and put them in a new table. Note that the `[source].var='1'` varies for different tables.

   ```
   SELECT TOP n * INTO tablen
   FROM source
   WHERE [source].var='1';

   # concrete example 
   SELECT TOP n * INTO table1
   FROM source
   WHERE [source].var1='1';

   SELECT TOP n * INTO table2
   FROM source
   WHERE [source].var2='1';        

   SELECT TOP n * INTO table3
   FROM source
   WHERE [source].var3='1';

   SELECT TOP n * INTO table4
   FROM source
   WHERE [source].var4='1';

   SELECT TOP n * INTO table5
   FROM source
   WHERE [source].var5='1';
   ```
2. After making *n*-tables from the first step, I concatenate them using a query.

   ```
   # code2
   SELECT * FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM table2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM table3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM table4
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM table5
   ```
3. Finally I put the results of number two into a new table so I can use it.

   ```
   SELECT * 
   INTO dest
   FROM code2
   ```

Does anyone know how to put these set of tedious tasks into one SQL query so that I don't have to repeat 15 times?

Comment: What are you trying to do with those tasks?

Comment: Just to get the top _n_-rows from a table with separate criteria and putting them all together again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill try to answer this, but this is my first answer so go easy on me. First I'm not sure if the source table is the same for each "TOP" row query. If it is then you dont need tables, 1-5. Unless of course you want the 5 temp tables for some reason...and I assume you know what you're doing with UNION ALL.

Just query the original table inline:

```
 select a.* into dest
 from (select TOP n *
       from source
       where source.var1='1'
       UNION ALL
       select TOP n *
       from source
       where source.var2='1'
       UNION ALL
       select TOP n *
       from source
       where source.var3='1'
       UNION ALL
       select TOP n *
       from source
       where source.var4='1'
       UNION ALL
       select TOP n *
       from source
       where source.var5='1'
      ) a
```

Comment: Happy New Year @riverdog! This is topnotch!